# Help with sequence problem, expressing it as a function of a?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm working on a problem set for a math course right now and I've come across a problem that I am having some difficulty understanding/solving. The problem is below:

---

Consider the sequence: [image]

for different values of a. Try to generalize the value of the limit as a function of a; give a written discussion as to why your limit value or values should be true mathematically.

---

I do not understand the part where I must determine some function of a. I would really appreciate some from anyone in understanding this problem.

Thanks guys

Comment: Pick your favorite values for $a$; perhaps $a = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ and compute the limit. What do you get?

Comment: Note that the exponential $e^n$ gets larger faster than $n^a$, as $n$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You are given $\left\{\dfrac{n^a}{e^n}\right\}$.

Let's try arbitrary values of $a$ and see if we can establish a pattern.

Let's try $a= -100, 0,10$ respectively.

$a=-100:$

$\left\{\dfrac{n^{-100}}{e^n}\right\}=\left\{\dfrac{1^{-100}}{e},\dfrac{2^{-100}}{e^2},\ldots, \dfrac{1000^{-100}}{e^{1000}},\ldots\right\}\to 0$.

$a=0:$

$\left\{\dfrac{n^{0}}{e^n}\right\}=\left\{\dfrac{1}{e^n}\right\}\to 0$.

$a=10:$

$\left\{\dfrac{n^{10}}{e^n}\right\}$=$\left\{\dfrac{1^{10}}{e},\dfrac{2^{10}}{e^2},\ldots, \dfrac{100^{10}}{e^{100}},\ldots\right\}\to 0.$

Noting that as $n$ approaches infinity, the denominator $e^n$ grows faster than the numerator $n^a$ (regardless of what $a$ you select), and ends up being much bigger than the numerator after you get to a large enough $n$, you can conclude that the limit of the sequence converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

*If $a\geq0$ then $\displaystyle0\leq\frac{n^a}{e^n}\leq\frac{n^{\lceil a\rceil}}{e^n}$ how $\displaystyle\frac{n^{\lceil a\rceil}}{e^n}$ have form $\infty/\infty$, you can use L-hopital and you proof,  $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{\lceil a\rceil}}{e^n}=0$.

*If $a<0$ then $\displaystyle0\leq\frac{n^a}{e^n}\leq\frac{1}{e^n}$ and how  $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^n}=0$.

And then for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$,  we obtain $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{ a}}{e^n}=0$.

God bless

Comment: In the second step, if $a<0$, is more easy see that $\displaystyle\frac{n^a}{e^n}=\frac{1}{n^{-a}e^n}$ and this have form $1/\infty\rightarrow0$, I think the second inequality no is correct if $-1<a<0$.

Answer (score 0):

A simple proof,
assuming you know that
$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^k}{k!}$.

Let $m$ be an integer
such that
$m \ge a$.
Then
$e^x > \frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$
or
$\frac{x^a}{e^x}
\le \frac{x^m}{e^x}
< \frac{(m+1)!}{x}
$
and the right side goes to zero
for large enough $x$.